# Change TeX Live Main Repository

Tags: texlive

I'm now using TeX Live 2016 Pretest. 
After the pretest, I should change the current repository to local repository due to download speed.

My current system is in Windows 10. Can you explain how to change the main repository link to another one?

Comment: Maybe related here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326239/16920 We have not managed to solve a similar case in Debian 8.5 Linux.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As detailed in the `tlmgr` help, you want

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

run as Administrator/`sudo` if your TeX system was installed in that way. The above points `tlmgr` to the mirror network, almost always what you want.

Comment: Does this work for TeXLive 2016? - - Related case here, has been open for a long time already http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326239/16920

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The linked question says that the installation is TL'15, so it can't work with the TL'16 repositories. A fresh installation of TeX Live will be needed: there were non-compatible changes in the data structures between the two years.

Comment: See the thread again. The system has both TeXLive 2015 and 2016. It was my mistake that TeXLive 2015 stayed there. I did not know that it exists in the system still. - - How can you troubleshoot there further?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Can you pop into [TeX-sx chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends): the issue you have is nothing to do with the question here (which is specifically about the pretest vs release set up)

Answer (score 14):

Joseph Wright's answer should be your go-to in most cases, because the CTAN mirror network tries to automatically guess which mirror is closest to you. This presumably works well in North America and western Europe, where mirrors are abundant; it unfortunately finds sub-optimal mirrors elsewhere in the world (relying on physical proximity). If you encounter a slow connection, you might wish to choose a mirror manually.

An updated list of official mirrors is available [on the CTAN website](https://www.ctan.org/mirrors). Use

```
tlmgr option repository <CTAN/mirror/root/URL>/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

to change texlive's default repository, or

```
tlmgr -repository <CTAN/mirror/root/URL>/systems/texlive/tlnet ACTION
```

to use a specific repository for a single action, without changing the defaults. `ACTION` may be any action you would perform with `tlmgr`, e.g. `update --all`.

The mirror root URL would be `http://mirror.ctan.org/` for the automated mirror; to choose a different one, use the `http` link associated with the mirror you wish to use; For example, if the link to mir­rors.rit.edu (Rochester, New York) is `http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/`, so you would use

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

(NY is on the internet backbone, so this mirror happens to be a good one to try if you experience a slow connection.)