# Unable to connect via tlmgr

Tags: tlmgr

Recently, when I want to use `tlmgr`, I get the following connection error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>tlmgr install tablefootnotes
No connection to the internet.
Unable to download the checksum of the remote TeX Live database,
but found a local copy so using that.

You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror;
see the information and examples for the -repository option at
https://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html
(or in the output of install-tl --help).

TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.asis.io/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: unknown)
tlmgr.pl install: package tablefootnotes not present in repository.
tlmgr.pl: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

However, network is working

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [216.58.207.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.207.78: bytes=32 time=135ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.207.78: bytes=32 time=132ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 216.58.207.78:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 132ms, Maximum = 135ms, Average = 133ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Windows\system32>ping ctan.org

Pinging ctan.org [176.28.54.184] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 176.28.54.184: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=46
Reply from 176.28.54.184: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 176.28.54.184:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 97ms, Maximum = 102ms, Average = 99ms
Control-C
^C
```

Any idea about that?

UPDATE1:

I used the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313271/change-tex-live-main-repository) to change the default repository. However, still I can not install the package I want. Although it says 2018 is frozen, the latest release in the ctan website is also 2018. So, I don't know what is wrong with that.

```
C:\Windows\system32>tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr.pl: setting default package repository to http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet

C:\Windows\system32>tlmgr install tablefootnotes
TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.um.ac.ir/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package tablefootnotes not present in repository.
tlmgr.pl: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Comment: Your error message mentions `ctan.asis.io`. Can you ping that site? It won't connect for me if I try to load that page in a browser.

Comment: Neither ping nor browser works for that address. How can I change the mirror?

Comment: `--repository url` you can find a list of mirror urls via tug.org/texlive

Comment: I tried two mirrors from `https://ctan.org/mirrors`. Commands `tlmgr install --repository ftp.harukasan.org tablefootnotes` and `tlmgr install --repository ftp.ccu.edu.tw tablefootnotes` both return `Cannot determine type of tlpdb from .....`

Comment: Please see the UPDATE1.

Comment: remove the s its tablefootnote (singular)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```bash
sudo tlmgr --repository http://www.preining.info/tlgpg/ install tlgpg
```

from https://texlive.info/tlgpg/

Comment: This solution worked. Others not tested. However, the mentioned website did not mention url above. So I guess it's better and safer (?) to use http://www.texlive.info/tlgpg, i.e. "sudo tlmgr --repository http://www.texlive.info/tlgpg install tlgpg".

Comment: The website preining.info appears to belong to the [maintainer of tlcontrib repository](https://contrib.texlive.info/) so it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

While running my texlive installation under Linux, I had exactly the same problem with tlmgr. That was pretty annoying. I presume the bug is somehow connected to the 2018 release already being frozen (while 2019 still not out there).

For me it helped to download and run the `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` script from http://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html. I ran it first without options, which I believe did the trick.

Comment: Your answer may be relevant to another question however in this case the real problem was `tlmgr.pl install: package tablefootnotes not present in repository.` because the OP used the wrong package name. AND was having intermittent repository issues. Your solution is not recommended for the future unless the user has a very specific need.