# ! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found in R Studio MacBook Air

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac, r

This is a new user of R.

TikzDevice and ggplot2 have been installed in R Studio on MacBook Air.

An error occurred when trying to run the blue code in the screenshot.

I tried to use `tikzTest()` to check the error. The error was `! LaTeX Error: File 'tikz.sty' not found.` The full output of `tikzTest()` is after the screenshot.

Just wondering how to fix this error?

P.s. I've installed MacTex but could not find `tikz.sty` in packages or updates.

Much appreciated if some solutions could be provided.

[image]

```
tikzTest()

Active compiler:
    /usr/local/bin/pdflatex
    pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)
    kpathsea version 6.3.3

Measuring dimensions of: A
Running command: '/usr/local/bin/pdflatex' -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory '/var/folders/1t/bjl9jstj6zl4gx_lxwkfvxqw0000gn/T//RtmpuavW7G/tikzDevice13b806c1dd9fc' 'tikzStringWidthCalc.tex'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

TeX was unable to calculate metrics for:

```
A
```

Contents of TeX file `tikzStringWidthCalc.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\batchmode
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=1] (TeX) {A};
\path let \p1 = ($(TeX.east) - (TeX.west)$),
    \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (TeX.east) -- (TeX.west)
    node{ \typeout{tikzTeXWidth=\n1} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Contents of log file `tikzStringWidthCalc.log`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.30)  14 MAY 2021 22:22
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tikzStringWidthCalc.tex

(/var/folders/1t/bjl9jstj6zl4gx_lxwkfvxqw0000gn/T//RtmpuavW7G/tikzDevice13b806c
1dd9fc/tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (/Users/waterqi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/te
x/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/waterqi/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)

! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.4 ^^M
        
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 220 strings out of 480954
 2975 string characters out of 5906449
 280518 words of memory out of 5000000
 17541 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,0n,50p,138b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>
```

Comment: What exactly did you install in order to run LaTeX with RStudio. Sometimes we see it installing BasicTeX which is a minimalistic LaTeX installation, which I assume does **not** include `tikz`.

Comment: Hi Daleif, I installed TinyTeX and TikzDevice in R studio. I also installed MacTex in a different location on the same laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You have the TinyTeX¹ distribution which does not necessarily include everything. The documentation for TinyTeX offers this advice:

> If you compile a LaTeX document and run into an error message like this:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `times.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

> It basically indicates a missing LaTeX package. Do not panic.

It then suggests running `tlmgr` from a command line to identify the needed package:

```
tlmgr search --global --file "/tikz.sty"
```

(the `/` at the beginning of the file name is to make sure you don't get all the files that end with `tikz.sty` but rather just the one with that actual name). This will give you output that has the lines:

```
pgf:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
```

the `pgf` on the first line is the name of the package you need to install. You can now, at your command line, type:

```
tlmgr install pgf
```

Files will be downloaded and afterwards all should be well.

---

1. Important note: MacTeX is a different installation than TinyTeX. MacTeX is a full TeX-live distribution which would include all the packages. It takes a while to download and a lot of space to install. TinyTeX is a subset of TeX-live which does not include all the packages and installs to a different location.

Comment: Thank you very much, Don.  I tried tlmgr_search('/tikz.sty') and get                                  tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
pgf:
 texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty                                                   Then, I tried tlmgr install pgf, but get
Error: unexpected symbol in "tlmgr install"                                                                 Not sure how to solve this issue. Much appreciated if some solutions are available.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578950/202780

Comment: It might also be the case that, if you installed tinytex more than a month or so ago, you're bumping into the annual texlive freeze. and you may need to update everything: try `tlmgr update --self --all` then 
`tlmgr path add` then
`fmtutil-sys --all`

Comment: Thanks Don. The tex.stackexchange.com/a/578950/202780 works :)